# equivalent $(shell external_command) call on Windows

Tags: windows, shell, makefile, cmd, qmake

I'm generating a makefile that I want to work in both linux and windows which creates a defined variable with my SVN build number which I would like to use in my code. (note: I don't want the build version hard coded in the makefile, but rather I want the version gathered at the time I build my project)

I found out how to do this in Linux with `'BUILDVERSION="$(shell svnversion)"'`

But how can I do this in windows?

I've google searched on things like "makefile $(shell) equivalent on windows", but haven't been able to find the equivalent call. (I'm not all that experienced with makefiles so I'm not even sure what would be good keywords to search on to find this)

Thanks in advance for any advice.

Answer (score 1):

If you use GNU make on Windows, then you can do it exactly the same way.

If you use some other make, such as `nmake`, then I don't think you can do it (but I'm no nmake expert).  For sure you won't be able to use the same makefile on both Linux and Windows unless you use a portable make (e.g., GNU make) on both systems.

Comment: my project is being developed in Qt. So qmake handles generating the makefile for windows or linux. In my .pro file I would specify `unix:DEFINES+='BUILDVERSION="$(shell svnversion)"'` which gets run on a linux machine. For windows I'm searching for the equivalent call...

Comment: Then you should add a "qmake" tag to your question since it's specific to qmake.  I don't know anything about qmake but I don't see why the same makefiles wouldn't work on both Linux and Windows, if both builds use qmake.